# Can't show tableview in my ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need a simple `UITableView` of 1 row and 6 columns, I'm trying to create a `UITableView` programmatically and add it on my `ViewController` but with no luck, I watched some tutorials and I don't really get what I'm doing wrong. Maybe if you guys take a look you could tell me.
This is my code:

```
class MainVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var mTableView: UITableView = {

        //STACKOVERFLOW *In the first line, I'm just positioning it randomly to see if I can get the table view to show, will change later.*
        var tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100), style: .plain)
        tableView.backgroundColor = .red

        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return tableView

    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 80/255, green: 135/255, blue: 179/255, alpha: 1.0)

        setupNavBar()
        self.navigationItem.searchController = mSearchBarController

        setupMainWeatherIcon()
        setupTableView()

        mTableView.dataSource = self
        mTableView.delegate = self

    }

    private func setupTableView(){

        self.view.addSubview(mTableView)


        mTableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        mTableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        mTableView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        mTableView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    }

    // MARK: TABLE VIEW METHODS!
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "forecastCell", for: indexPath)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to setup datasource for tableView

Add: mTableView.dataSource = self

UITableViewController add this automatically, UIViewController doesn't.

Also you forgot to setup height anchor... and Width. Or Top and Bottom Anchor

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure how I missed it, anyway, the table view still won't show on the ViewController.

Comment: You have to register cell for tableView. How did you created cell?

Comment: I didn't create the cell yet, I'm going to just create a class for the cell. But to my very limited knowledge, I should at least see the table view, even without cells. I guess I'm wrong?

Comment: Put breakpoint and see if application enters cellForRow method. If it does, try adding: 
                    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: { (_) in
                        print(self.mTableView.frame)
                    })

At the end of setupTableView()

To see its frame

Comment: Oh you forgot to setup height anchor... add it. and widht.
Or Top and Bottom Anchor

Comment: Thanks! Finally I can see it on the screen now. feeling kinda stupid :\ .. but that's okay, I'll learn for the next time. Thanks again!

Comment: Btw, thats not the way you want to add Table to UIViewController. Use Storyboard or xib and bind it with @IBOutlet. Its ok to use it like this for some things, but not how apple intended . And in storybord add cells, or create them throught xibs and register them for table. Good luck ^^